# phpMyAdmin. User disappears in privileges tab

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, privileges

I'm trying to assign privileges to a specific user but the user disappears after unchecking all the privileges on a table I don't want the user to use. I know the user is still there because I can run an SQL query on it and it won't let me create another with the same name.

This is what I'm doing:

-Create new user at localhost. Uncheck global privileges, grant all privileges on database.
-Go to specific table, uncheck all privileges. "You have updated the privileges..."
-Go to another table, go to the privileges tab and the user is not there. It's not in the databases' privileges tab either. Nowhere to be found.

What is the cause of this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Why would a user that _has no_ privileges _be_ in the privileges table?

Comment: I'd like it to have privileges, but I'm not getting the chance to. Is there a way to access users that don't have privileges?